# amd graphics for ubuntu 17.10

Tags: graphics

I have a lenovo laptop g50-70 equipped with integrated intel card and and R5 M230.

but the ubuntu os lists only the intel graphics and inside the additional drivers, there is no mention for the amd graphics card too.

what should I do to use the amd instead of intel card??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek of this, found courtesy of DuckDuck. But, be aware, the recent changes in Ubuntu 17.10 to Wayland may not be supported within the AMD Drivers.

https://community.amd.com/thread/183011

Voila.

Comment: thanks man. that didn't work. I think ubuntu and laptops with 2 graphics cards are an unsolvable equation.